# How to connect to QuickBooks online from a desktop application

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online, qbxml

OK. This question has been asked a number of times and answered. However, it seems Intuit changed things on their part so:

- Their own latest documentation is no longer correct
- All the answers I found so far on the Internet no longer work

Therefore, the only option left is to ask the same question again.

I'm building a console application in C# that need to import data (invoices, customers, etc.) to QB online. It is an internal integration application that will be used by only one company. I definitely do not want to go on the SaaS route.

By all accounts it seems that I should the QuickBooks QBXML SDK v12 **and** should registered the application in QBOE at "www.appreg.intuit.com". However, this address no longer exists and the registration procedure has changed. QBOE currently support three types of applications:

- QuickBooks API - SaaS
- Customer Account Data API
- Payments (QBMS) App

By considering the functionality I need (create invoices etc.) I should probably create a "QuickBooks API" application. However, this is a SaaS application which is unusable to me.
The "Customer Account Data API" is definitely not what I need.
The only option left is the "Payments (QBMS) App" which does not seem to be the right choice either. However, this is the only one of the three application types that can be either hosted or desktop and have "AppID" and "AppLogin" attributes described in various integration articles on the Internet when using the traditional SDK.

Therefore, I created a "Payments (QBMS) App" (Desktop, Production), followed documentation and articles, did all required settings and used the traditional SDK COM objects to connect to QuickBooks.

During the first connection attempt I approved the application in my QBOE account and set the connection token. Gave all permissions to the connection with no user authentication required.

In the end all I got is the following uninformative exception thrown by the  `QBSessionManager.BeginSession` method:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040403): Problem communicating with QuickBooks Online Edition
```

If I turn on log-in security a dialog appears prompting me to log-in and paste a ticket. Upon opening the log-in URL
    https://login.quickbooks.com/j/qbn/sdkapp/sessionauth2?serviceid=2004&appid=[AppID]

the following message appears

```
There is a problem with sharing your financial data between applications.
Error Message: Application [AppLogin] is not designed to work with service 2004
```

I also tried using qbXML directly which resulted in a "400 Bad request" error.

Is connecting to QBOE via the SDK still supported and what I'm supposed to do to achieve that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go here to create a QBOE application - http://developer.intuit.com/Application/Create/QBOE.

Comment: With the new "Harmony" interface, this is broken. Probably not a great way for people to go anymore since it won't work at all in another few months.

Answer (score 0):

You should use traditional QBSDK.

Please refer this link - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits/0250_qb

Thanks

Comment: I'm using the traditional SDK. However, it does not seem to work as described. Please read my question in full before responding.

Comment: I edit the question to make it explicit that I'm using "QuickBooks QBXML SDK v12".

Comment: In the end of your post, you've asked "Is connecting to QBOE via the SDK still supported". I confirmed that it is still supported. In QBSDK's link, there are couple of important pages. Have you seen the sample programs pages ? https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits/0250_qb/0050_documentation/sample_code.I'm adding qbsdk tag in your qts. Thanks

Comment: I did follow docs and examples. The "BeginSession" method is always giving the vague error "Problem communicating with QuickBooks Online Edition". In my view the problem is that the application I created in QBOE is "Payments (QBMS) App" application. The docs state that I should create an application at the following URL **www.appreg.intuit.com** which **no longer exists**. Instead applications are created at https://developer.intuit.com/Application/List. There are three types of applications supported and the "QBMS" is the **only** type that have "AppID" and "AppLogin" described in the docs.

Comment: It looks like something has changed and registering a desktop application in QBOE as described in "Intuit QuickBooks SDK - Programmer’s Guide v12" and various online tutorials is no longer possible.

Comment: Can you please raise a support ticket? https://developer.intuit.com/Support/Overview

Comment: With the new "Harmony" interface, this whole AppReg process is broken. Probably not a great way to recommend people go anymore since it won't work at all in another few months.